# How to identify that a specific text was sent by socket, to activate a command, with if ==?

Tags: sockets, if-statement, server, client

I have a code that sends a pre-established text by socket. If the default text sent is "hi", I want that in addition to receiving the hi, print that the text sent was hi. I'm a beginner, I tried doing if msg == hi: but it didn't work. How do I do it please?

Server

```
from socket import *
host = gethostname()
port = 8889

print(f'HOST: {host} , PORT {port}')
serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind((host, port))
serv.listen(5)

con, adr = serv.accept()

msg = con.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode())

if msg == "hi":
    print('A mensagem foi hi')
```

Client

```
from socket import *
host = gethostname()
port = 8889
cli = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cli.connect((host, port))

msg = ("hi")
cli.send(msg.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually updating your `msg` variable to the decoded string, you are just printing the string. When comparing `msg` to `"hi"`, `msg` still contains encoded bytes. You should add

```
msg = msg.decode()
```

or you might as well put it earlier:

```
msg = con.recv(1024).decode()
```